# Laravel seeder gives error. Class not found

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I'm a newbie in Laravel and and I'm teaching myself how to authenticate from a login table. I have migrated and created the table. Now, I'm trying to seed the data into the login table, but the command prompt is continuously giving me error, which says `Fatal Error, class login not found` and I have no idea what i have missed. So can anyone please help me. Here is the code that i have, and yes I'm using Laravel 4.3

```
<?php
class loginTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('login')->delete();
        login::create(array(
            'username'  =>  'sanju',
            'password'  =>  Hash::make('sanju')
            ));
    }
}


?>
```

Comment: Try running `composer dumpautoload`

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work for me. I tried it before

Comment: What is the result of `php composer.phar diagnose` and it should be `composer dump-autoload` with a hyphen

Comment: when i go with the composer.phar function it returns me: could not open input file: composer.phar and i have used the method composer dump-autoload and it does not work. Sorry

Comment: Including the full error message would help people track down exactly what went wrong

Comment: <"error":<"type":"Symfony\\Components\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException", "message":"Class 'Login' not found", "file":"C:\\xampp\htdocs\\hariyalihost\\app\\database\\seeds\LoginTableSeeder.php","line":7>}

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to create an Eloquent model for that table in order to use `Login::create()`. You can do that with a simple artisan command:

`$ php artisan generate:model Login`

This will generate a new Eloquent model in `app/models` directory which should look like this.

```
class Login extends Eloquent {

    protected $fillable = [];
    protected $table = 'login';

}
```

Your code should work after that. If it still doesn't make sure you run `composer dump-autoload`.

Comment: Hey, i am a bit close to yours. The solution worked but only 50%, now the error is base table or view not found. table hariyali.logins, but my table is just login so where did that logins come from. The extra s come from

Comment: Specify the table name as a class property in the Eloquent model class `protected $table = 'login';`. I've update my answer.

Comment: Eloquent automatically assumes the table name is the lowercase plural version of your model name, so in your case `Login` model name means it will automatically search for the `logins` table unless you specify the `$table` property for your model. You can read the [Eloquent Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent) to get more aquainted with the conventions.

Comment: Ok, now 80% the problem is fixed, now there is one more problem it says unknown column name 'updated_at',  do i need to add the timestamp() in my migration file. Is that error all about

Comment: Yes you could add that to the migration, but you could also add `protected $timestamps = false;` in your model class, if you don't want the model to use the default timestamps naming convention.

Comment: thanks a lot...thanks man!!It worked i will figure our about the the timestamp() in the laravel document. thanks dude

Answer (score 15):

**EDIT**

Now I see, the problem  is with your `login` class (with earlier question formatting the exact error was illegible). You should look again what's the name of file where you have `login` class and what's the name of class. The convention is that the file should have name `Login.php` (with capital letter) and the name of class also should be `Login` (with capital letter). You should also check in what namespace is your `Login` class. If it is defined in in `App` namespace, you should add to your `LoginTableSeeder`:

```
use App\Login;
```

in the next line after `<?php`

so basically the beginning of your file should look like this:

```
<?php

    use App\Login;
    use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
```

**EARLIER ANSWER**

You didn't explained what the exact error is (probably the error is for `Seeder` class)  but:

In `database/seeds/DatabaseSeeder.php` you should run Login seeder like this:

```
$this->call('LoginTableSeeder');
```

You should put into `database/seeds` file `LoginTableSeeder.php` with capital letter at the beginning.

Now, your file `LoginTableSeeder.php` file should look like this:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class LoginTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {

        // your code goes here
    }
}
```

you need to import `Seeder` with `use` at the beginning of file and again class name should start with capital letter.

Now you should run `composer dump-autoload` and now when you run `php artisan db:seed` it will work fine.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I missed out one thing. I named it this way loginTableSeeder.php, and yes i fixed it and now it looks like this, LoginTableSeeder.php. Now, here is my LoginTableSeeder.php code. <?php
class loginTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
 public function run()
 {
  DB::table('login')->delete();
  Login::create(array(
   'username' => 'sanju',
   'password' => Hash::make('sanju')
   ));
 }
}


?>, But, its not fixed yet.

Comment: @samhukiklsk As I mentioned the problem is probably that Seeder class is not found You need to have `use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;` line in this file after `<?php` as in my code above

Comment: @samhukiklsk I've edited my answer (answer is at the beginning)

Comment: the document is well and good but this error not mentioned in the documents of laravel. 

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/seeding
in my composer.json file autoload class is already there and set database in it. 

just running composer dump-autoload worked for me

Answer (score 10):

Just run 
`composer dump-autoload -o`
for the autoloader to pick up the newly classes because the database folder is not automatically autoloaded with PSR-4.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
composer dump-autoload -o
```

Comment: what if the escape is disabled by the hosting?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem but you can solve it by adding your namespace:

```
namespace yournamespace; 
use App\Login;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same problem. In my case, the composer was extremely old and after it's update everything runs Ok.

Update composer with the command:

$ composer self-update

Hope it can help others.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create Model

```
$ php artisan generate:model Login
```

and than in your seeder class Needed to add `use App\Models\Login;` to my loginTableSeeder file.